# Using Angular CLI to update to Angular 4

Tags: angular

I had an app that works with angular 2.3 and cli 1.0.0-beta18. I wanted to update to the latest and reinstalled `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` but I can't now work out what command to run to get updated config files and to get package.json upgraded to 4.x files. I can't see anything like this in `ng help`.

(I tried once before to run `npm install @angular.... @latest` per the Angular4 instructions, but left me in a terrible mess as the CLI does not always use the absolute latest it seems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating the CLI will not pull the latest version of Angular, that part is up to you (by changing @angular version values the package.json, and using `npm install`) for existing applications. If you start a new application with the latest CLI, it will install Angular 4 by default. Existing applications, whatever version of Angular they are on, will not be updated.

You could (read should) create a new application with the latest CLI, and copy your code to it. That may be easier than doing an in-place update considering the version of the CLI you are coming from. There were some config structure changes since beta 18. The build processes are a little more strict, too. AOT is the default with doing a prod build.

Your Angular code should just work with the latest version of the CLI and Angular, unless you are doing something unusual.

A good resource for updating to the latest CLI: [Updating Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli).

More good information: [Angular CLI migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update)

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Ugh, not the answer I was hoping for, but one I can work with

Comment: Understandable! Moving from one version to another of the CLI is okay, if you keep up with it. Otherwise, it can be a pain. Same thing with Angular itself. Good luck!